# http://127.0.0.1:86/ Script adrress

Tags: security, virus

-This address appeared in my win 10 proxy setting. Every time I turn it off it goes back on when I leave the proxy tab.

-When this issue appeared I got an error in browser saying that there is no internet connection even do I can browse the web on any other device.

-How can I fix this issue?

[image: Screenshot of my proxy setting tab]

Comment: It virus similar to proxy server virus, that all I know.https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/removing-a-proxy-virus-1270018080/ccf3081a-e282-4796-b1b6-770bf5c39c1a

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)